# Check if application is deployed in Tomcat using gradle

Tags: tomcat, gradle, cargo

I am using `gradle-cargo` plugin to deploy my war to tomcat server.

I call `cargoDeployRemote` task for this. However it throws me an error when the application is already deployed on the server.

```
Deploying [C:\jenkins\workspace\myapp\build\libs\myapp.war]
:cargoDeployRemote FAILED
:cargoDeployRemote (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 1.081 secs.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':cargoDeployRemote'.
...
...
BUILD FAILED
```

How to over come this? Is there a way where I can query the context url and find if it is already deployed?

Comment: `https://github.com/agrrh/SEWEB/blob/master/SewebServer/build.gradle` this script contained the script which checks if the context exists in the container or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After referring to the [docs](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-cargo-plugin) I'd investigate how exactly the following tasks work:

- `cargoDeployRemote`
- `cargoUndeployRemote`
- `cargoRedeployRemote`

And use appropriate combination of these tasks: e.g. maybe using `cargoRedeployRemote` will solve the problem? Or maybe call `cargoUndeployRemote` and `cargoDeployRemote` afterwards?