# How to check if application is deployed on Tomcat using gradle?

Tags: tomcat, gradle

How to check in gradle if application (client-server) is already deployed?
I am using [gradle cargo plugin](https://github.com/bmuschko/gradle-cargo-plugin).
I would like to do something like [this](http://etutorials.org/Programming/Java+extreme+programming/Chapter+10.+Tomcat+and+JBoss/10.5+Checking+If+a+Web+Application+Is+Deployed/), but with gradle.

[Answered stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28872606/check-if-application-is-deployed-in-tomcat-using-gradle) doesn't help.
I tried mentioned cargoDeployRemote, cargoUndeployRemote and cargoRedeployRemote combinations.
Instead I need some kind of mechanism to detect if webapp is already installed in Tomcat. If it is, then do first cargoUndeployRemote and then cargoDeployRemote (or alternatively just cargoRedeployRemote). If it is not installed, then do just cargoDeployRemote.

Any kind of help is very much appriciated.
Best regards,
misamas

Answer (score 2):

You could simply just ping to the *http://host:port/webapp-name* address and check if it returns 200 OK. Redeploy if not. You can write groovy in gradle script so this code should work

```
def url = "http://host:port/webapp-name"
def content 
try {
    content = url.toURL().openConnection().with { conn ->
        readTimeout = 10000
        if( responseCode != 200 ) {
              // redeploy
        }
    }
}
catch( e ) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I am so sorry, I said web application, but it really isn't web app. It is client - server  application. I corrected the question. So when  trying to do "http://host:port/webapp-name" it will always return 404. Is there any alternative to the solution you proposed?

Comment: please see comment above @mushfek0001

Comment: Can you clarify a bit more. How client-server interacts? I mean via which protocol? There must be some way similar to the procedure I've mentioned above to let client know about server state.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. It uses java remoting and underneath it ends up with HTTP protocol. @mushfek0001 hope it clarifies things a bit.

Comment: Hey, did you see the comment above.  @mushfek0001  Could you please comment on that? What could be my alternatives? How could I detect some url client is asking server, also in code snippet you've given, I don't see where responseCode is defined, I only see content (I don't understand it)

Comment: Hi, sorry to leave you hanging man. I was AFK for a while. Anyway, even if it only deals with RMI or stuffs like that it should still receive ping. Have you tried leaving out the web-app part of the URL I mean pining at host:port? You can also check if there's any process running at that port using netstat. You can execute unix commands in gradle. So try executing netstat -ntlp | grep <port> If there's any process running at that port it'll return process details. You can try tailing catalina log too. It contains server start/stop log messages.